# Unable to source profile: export: Command not found

Tags: java, linux, shell

I encounter a problem when trying to source the /etc/profile in Linux.
I run the following command in Linux command line as root:

```
# vi /etc/profile
```

Add two lines to profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin
```

save profile.

```
# source /etc/profile

Error:
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/generic/bin:/usr/local/bin: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
Badly placed ()'s.
```

I don't know why this "command not found" error occurs.
The existing workarounds seem not helpful to my issue.

Thanks

Comment: What shell do you use? `Badly placed ()'s.` sounds like tcsh which indeed doesn't have `export`.

Comment: i am not sure if you do it on purpose PATH=$PATH:/  but can you try 
`export PATH=$PATH/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news: `/etc/profile` is compatible with Bourne compatible shells only (sh/bash/ash etc.)

The good news: you could write your own 'profile' file and source it into your script:

`cat /somewhere/your-sourced-file`

```
setenv JAVA_HOME '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java'
setenv PATH $PATH':/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin'
```

and then use `source /somewhere/your-sourced-file` to include it into your csh script.

Comment: I use echo &0 to show the shell which shows csh. But in /etc/profile, there are other lines containing "export" command, when I rewrite the profile and source it, the "export: Command not found." still shows.

Comment: The bad news: /etc/profile was created for Bourne compatible shells only.
The good news: you could write your own command file and source it into your script:
`cat /somewhere/your-sourced-file`
`setenv JAVA_HOME '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java'`
`setenv PATH $PATH':/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin'`

and then use
`source /somewhere/your-sourced-file`
to include it into your csh script.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot.